# Wagtail-In django how to get page attributes from page id

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, wagtail

I get wagtail page id from url

```
https://www.example.com/results?id=14&id=15
```

In views.py

```
def get_data(request, **kwargs):
    resources = request.GET.getlist('id')
```

how to get relevant page attributes with the help of page id ?

In models.py

```
context['selected_resources'] = ??
```

so that i can render it in template like this

In results.html

```
% for resource in selected_resources %}
 <p>{{resource.title}}</p>
 <p>{{resource.description}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What did you want to do in models.py, What you mean by page objects?

Comment: I mean page attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`filter` with an `id__in` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
resource_ids = request.GET.getlist('id')
context['selected_resources'] = ResourcePage.objects.filter(id__in=resource_ids)
```

This assumes that the IDs you're passing in the URL always refer to the same page type (`ResourcePage` in this example). This is probably a safe assumption - if there's a mix of page types, you can't really guarantee that they all have a `description` field, so you can't do anything useful in the output. But if you really do need to deal with multiple different page types (which all have `description` defined on them), you can do this as follows (at the cost of some additional database queries):

```
context['selected_resources'] = Page.objects.filter(id__in=resource_ids).specific()
```